# Concat string and eval

Tags: bash

I'am trying to output an inline status with date

```
now="date -Iseconds"
echo "[" eval $now echo "] my log status"
```

this returning line

```
now="date -Iseconds"
echo "["; eval $now; echo "] my log status"
```

I don't whant to do

```
now=`date -Iseconds`
```

Because time clock between 2 logs status and it store the time when the variable is initialized

Comment: Don't use eval if you don't know what you are doing. You can use a subshell `echo "[ $($now) ] my log status"`. But also you shouldn't  save commands to variables, so you can use an array instead `now=(date -Iseconds)` and access using  `${now[@]}`.

Comment: *Arguments* can be saved in an array; *commands* should be wrapped in a function.

Comment: @chepner How come?

Comment: Because `"${now[@]}"` is only slightly better than `$now`; it avoids unwanted word-splitting and pathname expansion, but still only works for a small subset of valid commands. It doesn't work with pre-command environment modifiers, redirection, pipes, or compound commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function:

```
now() { date -Iseconds; }

echo "[$(now)] my log status"
```

Even better, you can use a function that will output your message, with the date prepended:

```
msg_now() { printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date -Iseconds)" "$*"; }
```

and use as:

```
msg_now "my log status"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with just echo

```
echo $(date -Iseconds) my log status;

# 2017-08-16T01:18:25+00:00 my log status
```